# Filtering Columns by name in SAS

Tags: loops, sas, filtering, calculated-columns, sas-macro

I have a data set that contains year month in column names and I need get the data from column that contains the last date:

```
data have;
input sdo_202211 sdo_202210 sdo_202209;
datalines;
30 20 10
50 20 30
;
run;
```

Shape of result:

```
sdo_202211
30
50
```

Comment: What is the shape of your desired result?

Comment: What are you going to do with a dataset that just has the one variable separated from all of the other variables? Doesn't it lose most of its meaning if you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since your data always follows the format `sdo_yyyymm`, we can pull the `yyyymm` part, convert it to a SAS date, and find the maximum date. We'll use `dictionary.columns` to read all of the column names from the dataset.

```
proc sql;
    select name
    into :max_date
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname = 'WORK' AND memname = 'HAVE'
    having input(scan(name, -1, '_'), yymmn6.) = max(input(scan(name, -1, '_'), yymmn6.) )
    ;
quit;
```

`input(scan(name, -1, '_'), yymmn6.)` pulls the `yyyymm` part from the column name, then converts it into a SAS date.

This code saves the variable name into a macro variable called `max_date`. Now we can grab only the column with the max date, even if the variables are ever shuffled out-of-order:

```
data want;
    set have(keep=&max_date);
run;
```

Output:

```
sdo_202211
30
50
```